# display php code in header using wp_head()

Tags: php, wordpress, function

hey i am developing a plugin and i am almost near to close the plugin but i am facing a small problem in displaying the code  `<?php global $options; $options = get_option('p2h_theme_options'); ?>` below the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the header. i tried using echo but no use it is displaying in string rather of code. below is the code i tried to display:

```
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags' );
function my_facebook_tags() {
echo '<?php global $options; 
$options = get_option("p2h_theme_options") ?>';
}
```

thanks in advance for help..

Answer (score 0):

you should write code like this.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags' );
function my_facebook_tags() {
   //GLOBAL $options; 
   //$options = get_option("p2h_theme_options");
   //var_dump($options);
   echo eval("global $options; $options = get_option("p2h_theme_options");");
}
```

please change your code like this and then check the value is print or not?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply @renish but its not working. In header it is displaying as an `Array`

Comment: i changed my code, you should get value from array then print what you want to print.

Comment: as your code display's as `$options` but i want to display whole code `<?php global $options; $options = get_option('p2h_theme_options'); ?>` in the header. the example which i gave displays in string but not in code.

Comment: yeah.. actually i am calling through a global function and then displaying but to work my plugin i need to display the whole code until it displays in header the plugin wont work

Comment: ohk, then try `eval` function i think it's working. the `eval` function execute your code in header.

Comment: @RenishKhunt i tried with eval it is showing an error in the code